# Fabric Twitter Android: update status only once(403 Forbidden)

Tags: android, twitter

I try to create login and update status in Twitter. I use Fabrica and Twitter. Permissions: read and write.
My code Login:

```
loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a
                // TwitterSession for making API calls
                session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                token = authToken.token;
                secret = authToken.secret;

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        });
```

It's ok, the method success is calling. Next my updateStatus method:

```
session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient(session);
                StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
                statusesService.update(strMessage, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<Tweet>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<Tweet> tweetResult) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

When I try it at first - all was okay, my status was updated in twitter. But when I post status next - all time calling failure method and printStackTrace is next:

```
W/System.err﹕ com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 403 Forbidden
W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:382)
W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I also try it in updateStatus method:

```
final StatusesService statusesService = Twitter.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService();
```

Why my status was updated only once? What is error and how to can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :
it worked on my end

```
  TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = Twitter.getApiClient();
            StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();


            statusesService.update(strMessage, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<Tweet>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```